# No Payment gateway Accounts connected Error

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign Sandbox to test sending envelopes with a Payment. I have 2 active Payment Gateways setup in my Sandbox account and have this has been working successfully for many months of ad hoc testing. Today when I ran another test I'm getting this error:

```
{
  "errorCode": "PAYMENT_GATEWAY_NO_ACCOUNTS_CONNECTED", 
  "message": "No Payment gateway Accounts connected"
}
```

I just double-checked my Sandbox account and I definitely have 2 active Payment Gateways on my account. I can't find any other references to what is causing this error, and can't see why I would be getting that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this - in case anyone else encounters this error check which account you used for your authentication. I have 2 users in my account and I had last authenticated as User 2 instead of User 1 (admin user). I didn't realise that the Payment Gateways are associated with just the admin user and not additional users on the same account.